# Что собой представляет SEL в obj-c?

Tags: objective-c, тестирование

В тесте по obj-c встречается вопрос с вариантами:

> Что собой представляет SEL?
>
> - Выбор
> - С-тип селектора сообщений
> - С-тип класса
> - Указатель на метод
> - Ничего из перечисленного

При этом допускается лишь один вариант ответа на вопрос. Насколько я понимаю под ответ в такой формулировке попадает второй и четвертый вариант. Или это не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не уверен, но скорее второе - там все-таки не указатель на метод (под указателем на метод я понимаю именно указатель на реализацию, если неверно - просьба поправить), более того, саму реализацию метода можно и подменить в рантайме - см. [method swizzling](http://darkdust.net/writings/objective-c/method-swizzling)